# Scala return value not what is expected

Tags: javascript, scala, functional-programming, closures

I am learning Scala as a personal interest and I'm perplexed by the return value of the following, of which I expect to eventually print 52:

```
def lexicalTest(a: Int) = {
  (b: Int) => {
    (c: Int) => {
        a + b + c
    }
  }
}

val step01 = lexicalTest(10)

val step02 = step01(10)


def plusThirty(a: Int, b: Int) {
  a + b
}

println(plusThirty(22, step02(10)))
```

If step02(10) surely returns 30, and it is of type Int, then why is my return equal to ()

FWIW: I am coming from the perspective of getting this kind of thing to work in JavaScript.

UPDATE: Thanks cookie monster, `def plusThirty(a: Int, b: Int) {` should read `def plusThirty(a: Int, b: Int) = {`

Comment: I don't know a thing about Scala, but I noticed you don't have a `=` in the first line of your `plusThirty` function. I tried it in an online Scala evaluator, and that fixed it. `def plusThirty(a: Int, b: Int) = {`

Comment: Ahh! Thank you very much. Always stabbing ourselves in the back =) And it works

Comment: And the reason is that a function without a `=` is defined as a one returning `Unit` so result of your expression is not returned

Comment: A note about your code (once fixed with the introduction of the missing `=`): Every single curly brace you used was unnecessary!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In scala, As per §4.6 from [reference](http://www.scala-lang.org/docu/files/ScalaReference.pdf) if you declare below `function`:

```
def f(n:Somthing) = {}
```

Then the return type of `f` unless manually specified is taken (thanks to type inference) from the return type the block returns.

As per §4.6.3, the below is a `procedure`

```
def f(n:Somthing) {}
```

Where the return type of `f`is `Unit` even though it appears as `Int`. Infact if you manually use `return` rather than from implicit `return`, in repl it gives:

```
scala> def plusThirty(a: Int, b: Int) {
     |  return a + b
     | }
<console>:8: warning: enclosing method plusThirty has result type Unit: return value discarded
        return a + b
        ^
plusThirty: (a: Int, b: Int)Unit

scala> plusThirty(22, step02(10))
```

So as said in comments, it should be below else it would had been a procedure:

```
def plusThirty(a: Int, b: Int)  = {
  a + b
}
```

Comment: And that's why procedure definition syntax is going to be removed in a future version of Scala.

Comment: Martin Odersky himself now considers the "equal-free" shorthand for explicitly annotating the return type `Unit` was a mistake and recommends against it. I agree and my organization now requires the long-hand form in our code.